# How to organize Python modules for PyPI to support 2.x and 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, software-distribution, python-2.x

I have a Python module that I would like to upload to PyPI. So far, it is working for Python 2.x. It shouldn't be too hard to write a version for 3.x now.

But, after following guidelines for making modules in these places:

- [Distributing Python Modules](http://docs.python.org/distutils/index.html)
- [The Hitchhiker’s Guide to Packaging](http://guide.python-distribute.org/)

it's not clear to me how to support multiple source distributions for different versions of Python, and it's not clear if/how PyPI could support it. I envisage I would have separate code for:

- 2.x
- 2.6 (maybe, as a special case to use the new buffer API)
- 3.x

How is it possible to set up a Python module in PyPI so that someone can do:

```
easy_install modulename
```

and it will install the right thing whether the user is using 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: `easy_install` doesn't work for Python 3.x

Comment: The Distribute version of `easy_install` does work for Python 3.x (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute).

Comment: I added this question to: http://bitbucket.org/tarek/hitchhiker-guide-packaging/issue/10/how-to-support-both-python-2x-and-3x

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found that [`setup.py` for `httplib2`](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/source/browse/setup.py) seems to have an elegant way to support Python 2.x and 3.x. So I decided to copy that method.

The task is to craft a single `setup.py` for the package distribution that works with all the supported Python distributions. Then with the same `setup.py`, you can do:

```
python2 setup.py install
```

as well as

```
python3 setup.py install
```

It should be possible to keep `setup.py` simple enough to be parsed with all the supported Python distributions. I've successfully done so with a package [`cobs`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/cobs/) that supports 2.4 through 2.6 as well as 3.1. That package includes pure Python code (separate code for Python 2.x and 3.x) and C extensions, written separately for 2.x and 3.x.

To do it:

1) I put the Python 2.x code into a `python2` subdirectory, and Python 3.x code in a `python3` subdirectory.

2) I put the C extension code for 2.x and 3.x in a `src` directory under `python2` and `python3`.

So, the directory structure is:

```
root
  |
  +--python2
  |     |
  |     +--src
  |
  +--python3
  |     |
  |     +--src
  |
  +--setup.py
  +--MANIFEST.in
```

3) In the `setup.py`, I had these lines near the top:

```
if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
    base_dir = 'python2'
elif sys.version_info[0] == 3:
    base_dir = 'python3'
```

4) In the call to `setup`, I specified the packages as normal:

```
setup(
    ...
    packages=[ 'cobs', 'cobs.cobs', 'cobs.cobsr', ],
```

5) I specified the base directory for the Python code using a `package_dir` option (refer to step 3 for `base_dir`):

```
    package_dir={
        'cobs' : base_dir + '/cobs',
    },
```

6) For the C extensions, I gave the path:

```
    ext_modules=[
        Extension('cobs.cobs._cobs_ext', [ base_dir + '/src/_cobs_ext.c', ]),
        Extension('cobs.cobsr._cobsr_ext', [ base_dir + '/src/_cobsr_ext.c', ]),
    ],
```

That was about it for `setup.py`. The `setup.py` file is parsable by both Python 2.x and 3.x.

7) Finally, if you build a source distribution using:

```
python2 setup.py sdist
```

then it will by default pull in only the files that are specifically needed to build for that Python. E.g. in the above case, you would only get the files under `python2` in the source distribution, but not those under `python3`. But for a complete source distribution, you want to include the files for both 2.x and 3.x. To do that, create a `MANIFEST.in` file that contains something like this:

```
include *.txt
recursive-include python2 *
recursive-include python3 *
```

To see what I did, see the `cobs` source code on [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/cobs/) or [BitBucket](http://bitbucket.org/cmcqueen1975/cobs-python/).

Comment: Not sure why a write up like this isn't somewhere in one of the previously mentioned guides or anywhere else that I could find for that matter. I just uploaded my first pkg to pypi, it was written for py3 but I want to support py2 in a logical way. I think this will help.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use a single source distribution.

Comment: I could make a single source distribution, with directories e.g. `python2` and `python3`, each containing their own `setup.py` and the module code for that Python version. Is that what you mean?

Comment: That solution would seem to conflict with the advice "You should always run the setup command from the distribution root directory" in http://docs.python.org/3.1/install/index.html#platform-variations

Comment: @Craig McQueen: there should the only `setup.py` file. Take a look at packages that support both 2.x and 3.x on PyPI http://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=5&c=531&c=533

Comment: I've had a look at a few: `pyserial` uses `bdist_py2to3`; `blist` manages to write code that can be interpreted by 2.x or 3.x; `bitstring` is hacky; `crcmod` has separate 3.x code in a `py3` sub-dir (along with a separate `setup.py`. Nothing so far that looks promising for my situation.

Comment: I came across the `setup.py` for `httplib2` (http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/source/browse/setup.py) and that does something elegant with the `package_dir` parameter to `setup()`. That's looking more promising, and what I think I should do.

Comment: @Craig McQueen: Separate modules for 2.x and 3.x doubles maintenance work. It depends on how many workarounds your code required to stay with a single source for 2.x and 3.x whether it is worth it.